# SwiftUI: When I toggle the Bool showAnswer, all the answers to all the questions are displayed. I need to toggle each answer separately

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am unable to toggle the answer to each question independently. I tried adding a Bool to the struct holding the question and answer, but the error says the Bool is immutable.

https://github.com/williamallenmd/FlashCardTests

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsView: View {
  @StateObject var vm = ItemViewModel()
  @State private var showAnswer: Bool = false
  
    var body: some View {
      List(vm.items) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
          
          Button(item.question) {showAnswer.toggle()}
          showAnswer ? Text(item.answer) : Text(" ")
          
        }
      }
      .onAppear { vm.fetch()}
    }
}
```

Comment: But the VStack in a View of its own that has an item parameter, so every item can have its own State variable

Comment: You have many questions (item.question) but only one @State variable so of course all questions are affected. Perhaps better to add this functionality to the view model.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this simple approach, works well for me:

With this approach, there is no need for every item to have its own State,
or for an array of variables with keys, or to change your model.

```
struct ItemsView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ItemViewModel()
    @State private var showAnswer: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedItem: ItemModel = ItemModel() // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List(vm.items) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                Button(item.question) {
                    selectedItem = item  // <--- here
                    showAnswer = true
                }
                // --- here ---
                if showAnswer && selectedItem.id == item.id {
                    Text(selectedItem.answer)
                } else {
                    Text(" ")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.fetch()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the better answer for this situation. You are simply needing to reveal something in the UI. It is not going to be information that is necessary other places which should be kept by the model.

Comment: Yeah, it's a simple approach that works for me and answers
 the question that was asked by the OP. I did not speculate about any other requirements.

Comment: I have used it before, and it is the answer to the question asked. People forget they have access to the `.id` in an identifiable to make sure they are acting on the correct object.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware of the .id property and now I see how important and useful that is with List.  Thanks for helping solve my problem.

Comment: if this answered your question, could you mark it as correct please.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you only have **one** `@State` variable and it cannot change each Answer individually by itself. You either have to add a new property to `vm.items` which would be `showAnswer`. This would look like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ItemsView: View {
  @StateObject var vm = ItemViewModel()
  var body: some View {
      List(vm.items) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
          
          Button(item.question) {item.showAnswer.toggle()}
          item.showAnswer ? Text(item.answer) : Text(" ")
          
        }
      }
      .onAppear { vm.fetch()}
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can make the `showAnswer` variable an array, enumerating the items and using their `keys`.