# SwiftUI List: All items get updated instead of the selected item only

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

currently I am showing a list of items. When tapping the item the cell collapses and it should show more infos. Now I am facing the issue that when I tap one cell that all cells get triggered and instantly collapsing, too. I don't know what I am doing wrong since I thought that every object is identifiable, which I also conformed my object with (Identifiable).

Here is my code:

```
@State var areasHidden: Bool = true

List(viewModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { salesman in
                HStack {
                    ZStack {
                      Circle()
                        .stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 4)
                        Text(String(salesman.name.first!))
                    } .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                        Text(salesman.name)
                        if !areasHidden && salesman == salesman {
                            Text(salesman.areas.map { $0 }.joined(separator: ", "))
                        }
                    }
                }.onTapGesture {
                    areasHidden.toggle()
                }
            }
```

[[image: first]]
[image: second]

Comment: The struct for searchResults should have a property areasHidden which is toggled instead of a shared variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: When I toggle the Bool showAnswer, all the answers to all the questions are displayed. I need to toggle each answer separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710913/swiftui-when-i-toggle-the-bool-showanswer-all-the-answers-to-all-the-questions)

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, works well for me, no need for every `salesman` to have its own display `areasHidden` (it does not belong in there), as per my original comment link:

```
@State var areasHidden: Bool = true
@State private var selectedItem = "same type as salesman" // <--- here

var body: some View {
    // ...
    List(viewModel.searchResults, id: \.self) { salesman in
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 4)
                Text(String(salesman.name.first!))
            } .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0) {
                Text(salesman.name)
                if !areasHidden && selectedItem == salesman { // <--- here
                    Text(salesman.areas.map { $0 }.joined(separator: ", "))
                }
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            selectedItem = salesman // <--- here
            areasHidden.toggle()
        }
    }
    // ...
```